# Convert string list to non-string list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

In Python, I want to convert all strings in a list to non-string.

So if I have:

```
results =  ["['new','york','intrepid', 'bumbling']","['duo', 'deliver', 'good', 'one']"]
```

How do I make it:

```
 results =  [['new','york','intrepid', 'bumbling'],['duo', 'deliver', 'good', 'one']]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Comment: But it's likely that a more effective fix would be figuring out why that's the input in the first place and using an actual serialisation format instead of just stringifying lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`literal_eval()` from `ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is much safer than `eval()`:

```
import ast

results =  ["['new','york','intrepid', 'bumbling']","['duo', 'deliver', 'good', 'one']"]
results_parsed = [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in results]
print(results_parsed)
```

Output:

```
[['new', 'york', 'intrepid', 'bumbling'], ['duo', 'deliver', 'good', 'one']]
```

`ast.literal_eval()` only parses strings containing a literal structure (strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None), not arbitrary Python expressions.

Answer (score 1):

How about `eval` if you don't need to verify the correctness of input variables:

```py
results = [eval(x) for x in results]
```